# Filtering out text between brackets

Tags: c#, string, text

I have a text string, like this [A203][Tom D.][Local.VV-12], now i'm only intrested in the last text, [Local.VV-12], i'm able to delete everything using

```
string output = Regex.Replace(message, @" ?\[.*?\]", string.Empty);
```

but that deletes my last one too, how would i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
string output = Regex.Replace(message, @".*\[", "[");
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your regex pattern:

```
string output = Regex.Replace(message, @" ?\[.*?\](?i:\[.*?\])", string.Empty);
```

Returns `[Local.VV-12]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this using `Substring` function

```
string output=myString.Substring(myString.LastIndexOf("["));
```